# Can someone please explain how can this code print hello world? in assembly language

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, vga

```
org 100h

mov     ax, 0b800h
mov     ds, ax

mov [02h], 'H'
mov [04h], 'e'
mov [06h], 'l'
mov [08h], 'l'
mov [0ah], 'o'
mov [0ch], ','
mov [0eh], 'W'
mov [10h], 'o'
mov [12h], 'r'
mov [14h], 'l'
mov [16h], 'd'
mov [18h], '!'
mov ah, 0
int 16h

ret
```

Comment: It writes bytes (ASCII characters) into the first part of the video memory buffer, which - for color text mode - is located at 0xb800:0 in 16-bit mode on a DOS box.

Comment: See https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/how-to-write-directly-to-video-memory-in-ms-dos also.

Comment: Also [VGA text mode on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode). Note you should set the attribute bytes too.